# JBPM and Java 12

Tags: jbpm

I'm trying to learn JBPM 7, and I install Java 12.0.1 (OpenJDK) on windows 10. I download from https://www.jbpm.org/learn/gettingStarted.html file jbpm-server-7.23.0.Final-dist.zip and extract it, but after running jbpm-server/bin/standalone.bat this error occurs:

```
2019-07-11 12:32:00,856 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."kie-server.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."kie-server.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "kie-server.war"
at org.jboss.as.server@6.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:151)
at org.jboss.msc@1.4.3.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1736)
at org.jboss.msc@1.4.3.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1698)
at org.jboss.msc@1.4.3.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1556)
at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1364)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jboss.classfilewriter.ClassFile
at org.jboss.as.ejb3@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.iiop.handle.SerializationHackProxy.proxy(SerializationHackProxy.java:55)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.iiop.handle.HandleDelegateImpl.<init>(HandleDelegateImpl.java:58)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.IIOPJndiBindingProcessor.bindService(IIOPJndiBindingProcessor.java:108)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.IIOPJndiBindingProcessor.deploy(IIOPJndiBindingProcessor.java:77)
at org.jboss.as.server@6.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:144)
... 8 more
```

Next, I run docker image openjdk:12.0.1, copy jbpm-server-7.23.0.Final-dist.zip and unpack it, run jbpm-server/bin/standalone.sh and get **same** error.

Next I run docker jboss/jbpm-server-full:latest, and it works. But java version in this container is old - 1.8.

It is possible to run jbpm-server on modern java 12? How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue and downgrade java version to java 11. It works now