# Cannot start jbpm on http://localhost:8080/business-central

Tags: java, server, jbpm

I am a student trying to learn jbpm. Teacher wont help me, so this is my only hope.

I have installed java 13.
Server starts, but with some errors.
after i type "http://localhost:8080/business-central" i get a error 404.
Here is only the error (last) part of the log since the whole thing has more than 40 000 characters, and im allowed only 30 000 here:

```
18:32:14,470 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "business-central.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"business-central.war\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"business-central.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jboss.classfilewriter.ClassFile"}}
18:32:14,472 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "jbpm-casemgmt.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-casemgmt.war\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"jbpm-casemgmt.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.Error: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: override
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: override"}}
18:32:14,473 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "kie-server.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"kie-server.war\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"kie-server.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jboss.classfilewriter.ClassFile"}}
18:32:14,506 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "kie-server.war" (runtime-name : "kie-server.war")
18:32:14,506 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "jbpm-casemgmt.war" (runtime-name : "jbpm-casemgmt.war")
18:32:14,508 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "business-central.war" (runtime-name : "business-central.war")
18:32:14,509 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-casemgmt.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "jbpm-casemgmt.war"
      service jboss.deployment.unit."kie-server.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "kie-server.war"
      service jboss.deployment.unit."business-central.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "business-central.war"

18:32:14,757 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
18:32:14,760 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
18:32:14,760 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
18:32:14,761 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 14.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 6.0.2.Final) started (with errors) in 128590ms - Started 392 of 617 services (3 services failed or missing dependencies, 344 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: *Teacher wont help me* Why not? It's literally their job to help you. Maybe it's time to complain to the department head?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: override

Comment: Teachers can do whatever they want here unfortunately :/

Comment: @Roman Danilov - how do i fix that?

Comment: @bik92 could you donwgrade to java 8 for instance? And check the issue exists

Comment: @Roman Danilov- THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!!! I've lost 5 hours today because of this, and the solution was to downgrade java haha

Comment: Apparently, [java 11 should work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56989920/13317).

Answer (score 1):

1. Please follow the following instructions on the link below.
2. Use H2 Database.
3. Please create environmental variable JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.202.08 and PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin **(Use Java 8)**
4. Please insert the following entries to **standalone-full.xml** under JBoss_EAP_Home\standalone\configuration

```html
<system-properties>
        <property name="org.kie.example" value="true"/>
        <property name="org.jbpm.designer.perspective" value="full"/>
        <property name="designerdataobjects" value="false"/>
        <property name="org.kie.workbench.profile" value="FORCE_FULL"/>
        <property name="org.kie.server.location" value="http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server"/>
        <property name="org.kie.server.controller" value="http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller"/>
        <property name="org.kie.server.controller.user" value="<username>"/>
        <property name="org.kie.server.controller.pwd" value="<password>"/>
        <property name="org.kie.server.user" value="<username>"/>
        <property name="org.kie.server.pwd" value="<password>"/>
        <property name="org.kie.server.id" value="default-kieserver"/>
        <property name="org.kie.server.persistence.ds" value="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS"/>
        <property name="org.kie.server.persistence.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
    </system-properties>
```

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_process_automation_manager/7.6/html/installing_and_configuring_red_hat_process_automation_manager_on_red_hat_jboss_eap_7.2/assembly_installing-on-eap-deployable#eap_execution_server_configure_proc

This must resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to OpenJDK 11 helped. Previously i was using OpenJDK 13